# Using Twitter Bootstrap to Make Website and Contents Mobile Friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website (www.jocogolocal.com), and one of the objectives is to use Twitter bootstrapping to make all contents of the site fit the screen and eliminate as much white space as possible, but I feel like I am stuck because despite my efforts, it is not formatting the way I would like it, and sometimes it would even break the site with how bad / big the content / image banner gets. below is the code of both the master page and the page with the content, View Vendor, any help will be highly appreciated.

### Master page

```
    <asp:Table runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>  
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <div class="container">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/Images/JoCoGoBanner.png" class="img-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 "/>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
    <br />
```

### View Vendor

```
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                <p><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" Enabled="false" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'/></p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no full answer to this question other than to point you in the right direction to help yourself.

Tables should be used to display tabular data. They shouldn't be used for full site layout which is what you are essentially doing. One of the main selling points to bootstrap CSS is that it has already fleshed out flexible building blocks for you to use. I'm assuming this is a school project? Challenge yourself to build the layout without tabular structure using divs and the bootsrap classes (containers, rows, cols). With the current site it looks like you are missing the point of bootstrap all togather.

If you are attempting to eliminate white space, stop stacking containers inside of containers inside of containers. Each one of these elements has their own padding and margin values so every time you do this, you are fighting against yourself even more.

For Example, your first table is full of unnecessary elements that are fighting against what you are trying to do.

You:

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <td>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <div class="container">
                <img class="img-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-20" src="Images/JoCoGoBanner.png">
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Clean div with flexible layout using bootstrap:

```
<div class="jumbotron p-0"><img class="img-responsive col-lg-12 p-0" src="Images/JoCoGoBanner.png"></div>
```

Break free from tabular layout thinking or you will always be fighting against yourself dealing with flexible layout requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the point in the right direction. Yes, this was originally a school project, but now I am adding on some final touches for my client. There are a lot of things I notice I could have done a lot better, and it's really more of a learning experience than anything. The issue is that I didn't really understand bootstrapping, and the people I asked use bootstrapping for some minor elements in their table formats, which is why you see what I did in the post, but now I understand it a lot more. Thank you for the information.